# CSS formatting a linebreak

Tags: html, css

When I have the following code:

```css
.kitty {
    height: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content col-lg-12">
          <img src="http://www.downesvets.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kitten-package1.png"         alt="foo" class="kitty">
              textextext <br> textextext
          <img src="http://www.downesvets.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kitten-package1.png"  alt="foo" class="kitty"> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I want is that the text is that the `<br>` element applies to the text but that the images are still in one line. like this:

[image]

Which HTML or CSS do I have to use in order to achieve this?

Comment: if you are using the last version of boostrap i advice you to check my answer as you can simply rely on flex and use predefined classes ;) [am not looking for upvotes or accepted answer but simply for you to get more ways that are suitable for your situation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some unnecessary elements. I removed those and made your markup simpler.

```css
.kitty {
    height: 20vw;
    width: 20vw;
}
.kitty-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div>
          <img src="http://www.downesvets.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kitten-package1.png"         alt="foo" class="kitty">
              <span class="kitty-text">textextext <br> textextext</span>
          <img src="http://www.downesvets.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kitten-package1.png"  alt="foo" class="kitty"> 
    </div>
```

Comment: not sure the element are unnecessary :) he's cleary using bootstrap and the code seems a part of big code

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you can accomplish the layout with the least amount of mark up and elements, go for the simpler setup. I didn't see any reason to add `.row` and `.col-`. The simpler setup will accomplish the same fluid layout.

Comment: you didn't get me :) he's using bootstrap, the use of row/col is logic and here you don't see the necessity of it but it's necessary if it's a part of a big code ... i agree that here we don't need it, by the way the span you added is also useless and the div too ;) we can do without ...  But saying it's not necessary can lead to confusion and the OP may think he's doing wrong.

Comment: So neither of us is right or wrong since we do not know the full context. But based on the context that the OP exhibits in the example, I stand by my opinion that it's unnecessary. And regarding the span, how would you go about accomplishing the layout goals without another element wrapping the text in the middle?

Comment: you can check my answer to see that i didn't add any wrapper, but only CSS by using flex ... and that's why i was talking about bootstrap because even if we don't know the full context, since we know he's using bootstrap means that we can use some classes provided by bootstrap like i also did in my answer. As for me it's good to rely on existing classes provided by the framework we are using and only add extra HTML/CSS when needed

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use flex and you **don't** have to change your markup:

```css
.kitty {
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
}
.content {
  display:flex;
  /* For vertical & horizontal alignment */
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  /* */
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col-lg-12">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="foo" class="kitty"> textextext <br> textextext
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="foo" class="kitty">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it seems you are using Bootstrap, so if it's the V4, you will find ready classes for the CSS I added as this version rely on flex too.

```css
.kitty {
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="foo" class="kitty"> textextext <br> textextext
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="foo" class="kitty">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Then you need to put all the text in one `span` element and display it as `inline-block` like this:

```css
.kitty {
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
}

.content span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content col-lg-12">
      <img src="http://www.downesvets.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kitten-package1.png" alt="foo" class="kitty">
      <span>textextext <br> textextext</span>
      <img src="http://www.downesvets.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kitten-package1.png" alt="foo" class="kitty">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I used the `.content span` selector, but you may have to use a different selector (perhaps give a class to the `span`) if you have other `.content` elements with `span` children on the same page and don't want them to behave the same.